# Conditional sum of rows by a column value

Tags: r

I'm trying to sum rows that contain a value in a different column.

```
rowSums(wood_plastics[,c(48,52,56,60)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

The above got me row sums for the columns identified but now I'd like to only sum rows that contain a certain year in a different column.  I tried this

```
rowSums(mydata[,c(48,52,56,60)], na.rm=TRUE, mydata$current_year = '2015')
```

with no success.  I thought I might have to single out the year value from the column number, 7, in the initial column list.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably `rowSums(mydata[,c(48,52,56,60)] * (mydata$current_year == '2015') , na.rm=TRUE)` to return 0 in those rows or `rowSums(mydata[,c(48,52,56,60)], na.rm=TRUE)[mydata$current_year != '2015']` to remove those rows.

Comment: That looks like it works!  Can you tell me what the * does in the line of code?

Comment: @lmo method is also working. The `mydata$current_year == '2015'` will give you a vector with TRUE or FALSE. TRUE when the year is 2015. Now while multiplying TRUE will be coerced to 1 and FALSE to 0, therefore you will sum only records where year is 2015. Oh and the * is simply the multiplication sign ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say simply

```
rowSums(mydata[mydata$current_year == '2015',c(48,52,56,60)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

since I don't have the original data frame I cannot give you the result. But the idea is that you can select which rows you want before the comma while selecting which column you want. Is this clear enough for you?

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I only wrote it the way I did because I needed to filter by year after the fact, but your way is definitely the way to go.  Can you suggest a way to add multiple rows to the above that each contain 2015?

Comment: I will check your question tomorrow (already in bed now). Could you mark the answer as "answer" so that others can find it too? Thx.

Comment: Hi, can you be a bit more precise with your question? What do you mean exactly with "add multiple rows to the above"? Do you want to aggregate your data? If you specify a bit better what you want to obtain I am sure we can help you :-)

Comment: I can see now that it was not as clear as it could have been.  What I'm trying to do is pull out every column that contains a specific year.  I have current year, previous year1, previous year2, but none of them line up so a specific year could be in any of the three columns.  I wanted to find 2015 from all of the above columns whereas your example looks at mydata$current_year == '2015' and I was looking to add something like mydata$current_year == '2015', mydata$prev_year_1 == '2015', mydata$prev_year_2 == '2015' or mydata[c(,4:6)] I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You can simply use the `OR` operator `|` or `AND` `&` and add conditions like `rowSums(mydata[mydata$current_year == '2015' & mydata$prev_year_1 == '2015',c(48,52,56,60)], na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks fasttouch.  I got numeric (0) as the output so I'll have to see what that's all about, but you have been really helpful, thanks for everything!

Comment: Hey fasttouch, can you suggest a way to aggregate this line to group the row sums by a different column? max(rowSums(mydata[,c(48,52,56,60)], na.rm=TRUE)[mydata$current_year = '2015'])  I'm really stuck on this one.  I've looked at tapply and aggregate and can't fins a method for a line this complicated.  Thanks for anything you can offer.

Comment: Well if you consider this example `df2 <- data.frame(c(2000,2000,2001,2001,2002,2002), c(1,1,2,2,3,3) )` and then you define the column names `colnames (df2) <- c("year", "value")` you can sum values aggregating by the year with this `aggregate (df2, by = list(df2$year), FUN = sum)`. Does this help you?

Comment: Yes it really does!  Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!